# How to correctly qualify Result variable inside lambda

Tags: delphi, lambda

```
 function TFlatBlock.SelectRow(const C:TConditionR):TArray<TFlatRow>;
  begin
   Result := nil;
   if not Assigned(C) then Exit;
   //
   SearchRow(function(const R:TFlatRow):Boolean
    begin
     // Result from TFlatBlock.SelectRow !!!
     if C(R) then Result := Result + [R];
     // Result from lambda
     Result := false;
    end);
  end;
```

How to qualify var Result in this case? Yes I can use local variable instead, but maybe there is a way to do this without it.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. I tried to use `SelectRow` instead of `Result` (in Pascal, the function name can be used instead of the `Result` variable), but the compiler didn't allow that (instead it considered it a function call). I also tried `var OuterResult: T absolute Result` which made the compiler tell me "cannot capture symbol Result". That tells me it isn't doable. The same error message happens if you use an anonymous procedure instead of a function (in which case there is no ambiguity).

Comment: So it seems use local variable is only way?

Comment: I would guess so, yes.